# OpenCV w/ Tkinter : Lag & window problems

Tags: python, opencv, tkinter

I recently started using opencv with tkinter, and I started to have some problems that I can't seem to fix by myself...
The following code is supposed to play a video file while being able to choose which sub-directory you want to sort the file in. The problems I started to have is that the number of frames per seconds seems to act weird, since some clip I play seems "lagging", or don't have the right fps. 
Secondly, the code seems really messy, and thus buttons "disappear" after clicking on one for a moment.
And finally, I tried to do something so the buttons get as big as possible to fill the x axis on the bottom of the window, while the main frame, with the video playing, stays the same same size (so the video is supposed to stay in the middle, adapting his height and width to the frame size without changing the ratio) but that doesn't seems to work too.

Any help will be appreciated

PS: I am using Python 3.8 with openCV 4.1.2

Here is the code :

```
from tkinter import Tk, Button, Label, Frame
import os
import shutil
import cv2
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

x = 0

path = "path/to/folder"

def nbr():
    global x
    x += 1
    text.config(text=files[x])

class ButtonX (Button):

    def __init__ (self, *args, folder="", **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.folder = folder
        self.config(command=self.moveTo)

    def moveTo(self):
        global x
        global cap
        global width
        if cap.isOpened():
            cap.release()
        shutil.move(path + files[x], path + self.folder + "/" +files[x])
        print(files[x] + " moved to " + self.folder)
        nbr()
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(path+files[x])
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        width = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)*(height/cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)))

folders = [dI for dI in os.listdir(path) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(path,dI))]

allfiles = os.listdir(path)

files = [ fname for fname in allfiles if fname.endswith('.webm')]
files.sort(key=len)

print(folders)

window = Tk()
window.resizable(0, 0)
window.geometry("1600x908")
back = Frame(window)
back.grid(row=1, column=1)
window.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
window.grid_rowconfigure(2, weight=1)
window.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
window.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
player = Frame(back)
player.grid(row = 0, column=0)
buttouns = Frame(back)
buttouns.grid(row = 1, column=0)

text = Label(player)
text.grid(row=0, columnspan=4, sticky='w,e,n,s', padx=5, pady=50)

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(path+files[x])
fps = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, fps)
print(fps)
height = 600
width = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)*(height/cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)))

def show_frame():
    global cap
    global width
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, fps)
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    if frame is None:

        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(path+files[x])
        ret, frame = cap.read()

    cv2image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGBA)

    img = Image.fromarray(cv2image).resize((width, height))
    imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image = img)
    text.imgtk = imgtk
    text.configure(image=imgtk)
    text.after(3, show_frame)

buttons = []

z = 1
y = 0

for i in range(len(folders)):
    new_button = ButtonX(buttouns,text=folders[i], width=20, height=2, folder=folders[i])
    buttons.append(new_button)
    buttons[i].grid(row=z, column=y, sticky='w,e,n,s', padx=5, pady=5)

    y += 1
    if y == 4:
        y = 0
        z += 1

def deleted():
    global cap
    global width
    print("deleted " + files[x])
    if cap.isOpened():
        cap.release()
    shutil.move(path + files[x], "path/to/deleted" + files[x])
    nbr()
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(path+files[x])
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    width = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)*(height/cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)))

def skipped():
    global cap
    global width
    print(files[x] + " skipped")
    if cap.isOpened():
        cap.release()
    nbr()
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(path+files[x])
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    width = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)*(height/cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)))

delete= Button(buttouns,text="Delete", width=20, height=2, command=deleted, foreground="red")
delete.grid(row=z+1,column=2, columnspan=2, sticky='w,e,n,s', padx=5, pady=5)
skip= Button(buttouns,text="Skip", width=20, height=2, command=skipped)
skip.grid(row=z+1, columnspan=2, sticky='w,e,n,s', padx=5, pady=5)

show_frame()
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Attempting to show a frame every 3 milliseconds seems ambitious. That's an attempt at over 300 FPS, though likely much less since it takes a certain amount of time to display one frame. Is there a reason you need to display frames that fast?

Comment: As `.after()` is called at the end of the function, actually a frame is shown every (frame processing time + 3 ms).  `.after()` should be called at the beginning of the function in order to have a more constant FPS.  Of course the time parameter should be wisely chosen.

Comment: You need to decouple the decoding from display. Read the video asynchronously (in a dedicated thread) and add some buffer (queue with limited size) in between to mitigate any inconsistencies in decoding speed. The decoding thread will read frames as fast as possible, trying to keep the queue full. The GUI then pops the frames from the queue at its own pace and displays them. | However, before you delve into this, you should spend some time and refactor that code. A code review might help.